# XML subtrees - select specified child nodes only, but along with parent node

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, xquery

I have a simple but huge XML file, which consists of many `<file>` nodes, from which I want to select only 2 child nodes `<filename>` and `<bytes>` (for each `<file>`). I need a query that would return a collection of "simplified"  nodes consisting only of my 2 selected child nodes, like so:

```
<file>
  <filename>
  <bytes>
</file>
<file>
  <filename>
  <bytes>
</file>
```

But if I use following query: `//file/*[self::filename or self::bytes]`, I won't get 2 `<file>` nodes, but 4 childnodes:

```
<filename>
<bytes>
<filename>
<bytes>
```

My XML file and demonstration in PowerShell:

```
cls; 
[xml]$xml = 
@"
<root>
    <file>
      <filename>file1.txt</filename>
      <md5>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</md5>
      <bytes>69762</bytes>
      <executable>0</executable>
      <someothertag>x</someothertag>
    </file>
    <file>
      <filename>file2.txt</filename>
      <md5>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</md5>
      <bytes>78179</bytes>
      <executable>0</executable>
      <someothertag>y</someothertag>
    </file>
</root>
"@
#$xml

"This gives me entire file nodes with all childnodes: "
$result1 = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath "//file"
$result1
Write-Host
"The result is only selected nodes, but separately (without parent node):`n"
$result2 = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath "//file/*[self::filename or self::bytes]"
$result2
```

Any ideas?

PS
I know that I can accomplish this in various other ways, but I specifically want it to be done with xquery.

Comment: Are you sure you want it done with XQuery? What you have so far is simply an XPath expression. What tool are you using to process those instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple XPath expression will not be enough, as this cannot filter subtrees. You need to construct new result elements. This XQuery expression creates new `<file/>` elements, and includes all `<filename/>` and `<bytes/>` children:

```
for $file in //file
return element file {filename, bytes}
```

If you're able to use XQuery 3.0, you could use the *Simple Map Operator* to express a shorter syntax:

```
//file ! element file {filename, bytes}
```

Comment: This is FLWOR, right? No support in PowerShell by default, I'm afraid. But it's still the correct answer, thanks.

Comment: If PowerShell does not support XQuery, you shouldn't have _explicitly asked_ for it. FLWOR loops and element construction are the two basic elements that XQuery has as extension to XPath.

Comment: I wanted an XPath/XQuery solution, so I explicitly asked for it. That was just a side note.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to remove nodes selected by an XPath :

```
cls; 
[xml]$xml = 
@"
<root>
    <file>
      <filename>file1.txt</filename>
      <md5>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</md5>
      <bytes>69762</bytes>
      <executable>0</executable>
      <someothertag>x</someothertag>
    </file>
    <file>
      <filename>file2.txt</filename>
      <md5>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</md5>
      <bytes>78179</bytes>
      <executable>0</executable>
      <someothertag>y</someothertag>
    </file>
</root>
"@
#$xml

$dumy = $xml | Select-Xml -XPath '//file/*[self::md5 or self::executable or self::someothertag]' | Foreach {$_.Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_.Node)}
$xml.Save("c:\temp\test.xml")
```

Then edit `c:\temp\test.xml` to see the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution works, but it's just the kind the workaround I was hoping to avoid.